# Referential integrity in test data

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following insert:

```
    INSERT INTO TransactionActivityLog
    (
         [UserName]
        ,[ApplicationId]
        ,[ActivityType]
        ,[ActivityDate]
        ,[ActivityAllowed]
        ,[ResultCode]
        ,[ResultMessage]
        ,[CCTransactionId]
        ,[CCMasterTokenId]
        ,[PaymentTransactionStatus]
        ,[CCMasterTokenStatus]
        ,[AdditionalData]
        ,[TargetUserId]
        ,[BranchId]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        'UserName' + CONVERT(varchar(5), @TargetRowCount) -- UserName
        ,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -- ApplicationId
        ,FLOOR(RAND()*(4-0)+0) -- ActivityType
        ,DATEADD(DAY, RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1+DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)), @FromDate) -- ActivityDate
        ,1 -- ActivityAllowed
        ,NULL -- ResultCode
        ,NULL -- ResultMessage
        ,SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM CCTransactions ORDER BY NEWID() -- CCTransactionId (Needs referencing to CCTransactions table!)
        ,NULL -- CCMasterTokenId (Needs referencing to CCMasterToken table!)
        ,-1 -- PaymentTransactionStatus
        ,FLOOR(RAND()*(6-0)+0) -- CCMasterTokenStatus
        ,'AdditionalData' + CONVERT(varchar(5), @TargetRowCount) -- AdditionalData
        ,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' -- TargetUserId
        ,ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 5) + 1  -- BranchId
    )
```

The line:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM CCTransactions ORDER BY NEWID()
```

is producing errors in SSMS (SQL Server 2012).

My intention being; I want to randomly select a row from table **CCTransactions** and select its Id and insert its value in the above INSERT statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that line should be between brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like  below

```
null,
(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM CCTransactions ORDER BY NEWID())
null
...
```

Comment: Shows how new I am to this! Thank you both.